# Accessing value returned by scala futures

Tags: scala, future

I am a newbie to scala futures and I have a doubt regarding the return value of scala futures.

So, generally syntax for a scala future is

```
 def downloadPage(url: URL) = Future[List[Int]] {

 }
```

I want to know how to access the `List[Int]` from some other method which calls this method.

In other words,

```
val result = downloadPage("localhost")
```

then what should be the approach to get `List[Int]` out of the future ?

I have tried using map method but not able to do this successfully.`

Answer (score 30):

> The case of Success(listInt) => I want to return the listInt and I am not able to figure out how to do that.

The best practice is that you *don't* return the value. Instead you just pass the future (or a version transformed with `map`, `flatMap`, etc.) to everyone who needs this value and they can add their own `onComplete`.

If you really need to return it (e.g. when implementing a legacy method), then the only thing you can do is to block (e.g. with [`Await.result`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/concurrent/Await$.html#result[T](awaitable:scala.concurrent.Awaitable[T],atMost:scala.concurrent.duration.Duration):T)) and you need to decide how long to await.

Comment: So there is no way you can return the value of a Future without blocking? I thought that scala's goal was to be a more functional capable language. If Future callbacks return Unit, doesn't that support side-effects? Is there no way to get around this?

Comment: "So there is no way you can return the value of a Future without blocking?" How could you? The value isn't available yet. "If Future callbacks return Unit, doesn't that support side-effects? Is there no way to get around this?" Use `map`, `flatMap`, etc.

Comment: So my particular situation is checking to see if a user session is valid. In doing so, I make a request to a server to see if the session is valid. I use the Play Framework WS library which uses Futures. I just want to be able to return true or false from the isValidSession method without having to block the thread.

Comment: In this case "without having to block the thread" means "without having to wait for the server reply". How _could_ this be possible? If you don't want to block the thread, your method should return `Future[Boolean]` instead.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov It is possible, but you need a library like quasar which can do synchronous calls without thread blocking :)

Comment: @ZhekaKozlov It is quite unnecessary information for this level of explanation

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov Can you exactly give a sample code for this example if I have to get String from "Future[String]" using map, flatmap. I'm unable to get it using map/flatmap.

Comment: @Nandakishore You can't, just look at the return type. The point of the answer is that you generally don't need to. In the rare case in which it's necessary, you use `Await.result`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I guess Await.result is also blocking. I guess using for comprehension and yield works to get the value out of Future.

Comment: @Nandakishore No, they don't. The type of for-comprehension where you yield a `String` will be `Future[String]`.

Answer (score 16):

You need to wait for the future to complete to get the result given some timespan, here's something that would work:

```
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  def downloadPage(url: URL) = Future[List[Int]] {
    List(1,2,3)
  }

  val result = downloadPage("localhost")

  val myListInt = result.result(10 seconds)
```

Ideally, if you're using a `Future`, you don't want to block the executing thread, so you would move your logic that deals with the result of your `Future` into the `onComplete` method, something like this:

```
  result.onComplete({
    case Success(listInt) => {
      //Do something with my list
    }
    case Failure(exception) => {
      //Do something with my error
    }
  })
```

Comment: My problem is 

result.onComplete({
    case Success(listInt) => {
      //Do something with my list
    }
    case Failure(exception) => {
      //Do something with my error
    }
  })

will be a part of some method and I want to return the listInt value. How to do that ?

Comment: Either return future itself, or block until it completes.

Comment: You want the first version I suggested `val myListInt = result.result(10 seconds)` though watch out for timeout exceptions...

Comment: In Scala 2.10, you should use `Await` instead of getting the future's result directly: `Await.result(result, 10 seconds)`

Answer (score 8):

I hope you already solved this since it was asked in 2013 but maybe my answer can help someone else:

If you are using Play Framework, it support async Actions (actually all Actions are async inside). An easy way to create an async Action is using `Action.async()`. You need to provide a `Future[Result]`to this function.

Now you can just make transformations from your `Future[List[Int]]` to `Future[Result]` using Scala's map, flatMap, for-comprehension or async/await. Here an example from Play Framework documentation.

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext

def index = Action.async {
  val futureInt = scala.concurrent.Future { intensiveComputation() }
  futureInt.map(i => Ok("Got result: " + i))
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like that. If The wait time that is given in `Await.result` method is less than it takes the `awaitable` to execute, you will have a `TimeoutException`, and you need to handle the error (or any other error).

```
import scala.concurrent._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Try, Success, Failure}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

object MyObject {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        val myVal: Future[String] = Future { silly() }

        // values less than 5 seconds will go to 
        // Failure case, because silly() will not be done yet
        Try(Await.result(myVal, 10 seconds)) match {
            case Success(extractedVal) => { println("Success Happened: " + extractedVal) }
            case Failure(_) => { println("Failure Happened") }
            case _ => { println("Very Strange") }
        }      
    }

    def silly(): String = {
        Thread.sleep(5000)
        "Hello from silly"
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way I’ve found to think of a Future is a box that will, at some point, contain the thing that you want. The key thing with a Future is that you never open the box. Trying to force open the box will lead you to blocking and grief. Instead, you put the Future in another, larger box, typically using the map method.

Here’s an example of a Future that contains a String. When the Future completes, then Console.println is called:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

object Main {

  def main(args:Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val stringFuture: Future[String] = Future.successful("hello world!")
    stringFuture.map {
      someString =>
        // if you use .foreach you avoid creating an extra Future, but we are proving
        // the concept here...
        Console.println(someString)
    }
  }
}
```

Note that in this case, we’re calling the main method and then… finishing. The string’s Future, provided by the global ExecutionContext, does the work of calling Console.println. This is great, because when we give up control over when someString is going to be there and when Console.println is going to be called, we let the system manage itself. In constrast, look what happens when we try to force the box open:

```
val stringFuture: Future[String] = Future.successful("hello world!")
val someString = Future.await(stringFuture)
```

In this case, we have to wait — keep a thread twiddling its thumbs — until we get someString back. We’ve opened the box, but we’ve had to commandeer the system’s resources to get at it.

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't yet mentioned, so I want to emphasize the point of using `Future` with for-comprehension and the difference of sequential and parallel execution.

For example, for sequential execution:

```
object FuturesSequential extends App {

  def job(n: Int) = Future {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println(s"Job $n")
  }

  val f = for {
    f1 <- job(1)
    f2 <- job(2)
    f3 <- job(3)
    f4 <- job(4)
    f5 <- job(5)
  } yield List(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5)
  f.map(res => println(s"Done. ${res.size} jobs run"))
  Thread.sleep(6000) // We need to prevent main thread from quitting too early
}
```

And for parallel execution (note that the `Future` are before the for-comprehension):

```
object FuturesParallel extends App {

  def job(n: Int) = Future {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    println(s"Job $n")
  }

  val j1 = job(1)
  val j2 = job(2)
  val j3 = job(3)
  val j4 = job(4)
  val j5 = job(5)

  val f = for {
    f1 <- j1
    f2 <- j2
    f3 <- j3
    f4 <- j4
    f5 <- j5
  } yield List(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5)
  f.map(res => println(s"Done. ${res.size} jobs run"))
  Thread.sleep(6000) // We need to prevent main thread from quitting too early
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this one !