# Get value from future

Tags: scala, future

I have method

```
def seqAll: Future[Seq[User]] = dbConfig.run(users.result)

def getAll: Seq[User] = Users.seqAll.map(a=>a)
```

second method actually returns `Future[Seq[User]]`, but I want it to be just `Seq[User]`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing value returned by scala futures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713642/accessing-value-returned-by-scala-futures)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Await.result` but that means making the Future blocking and not asynchronous which takes away the point of using a future. Of course, blocking might not be a problem for you.

If you do want to get the result in a non-blocking way you do

```
Users.seqAll.map(a=>a) onComplete {
  case Success(result) => // use result for something
  case Failure(t) => // Handle error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With [`Await.result`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.concurrent.Await$):

```
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

def getAll: Seq[User] = Await.result(seqAll, 5.seconds)
```