# Transform Future into class or Map

Tags: scala, future, akka-http

I have a
`class ClassName(id:String, etc:String, long:Long)`

And a function that returns that object from the DB as
`Future[Option[ClassName]]`

I want to get transform that result (the Future[Option]) as, either a class with it's values, or a Map[String, AnyRef]

Does anyone knows how to handle this transform? I haven't been finding any answers on the internet

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713642/accessing-value-returned-by-scala-futures

Comment: What is the bigger picture of what you are to do?

Comment: @Tyler I want to extract a value from a database using Akka HTTP so I give it to the user. It's a project based on this one: https://github.com/ArchDev/akka-http-rest

Comment: @JavierBullrich can you be more specific as to what "give it to the user" means?  Are you responding to an HTTP request, displaying to a desktop giu or something else?  Also, what exactly is the thing that you are "giving" to the user?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I manage to create this function which returns me the class that is inside the future.

It's not generic, so it won't be very elegant, but it does the job

<del>def convertToClass(futureEntity: Future[Option[ClassName]]): ClassName = {
        var newClass: ClassName = null
        futureEntity onComplete {
          case Success(value) =>
            value match {
              case Some(s) => newClass = s
              case None => null
            }
          case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
            null
        }
        newClass
      }</del>

**EDIT:**
That method wasn't working. This one does:

```
def convertToMyClass(futureEntity: Future[Option[ClassName]]): ClassName = {
    var myClass: ClassName = null
    Await.ready(futureEntity andThen {
      case Success(value) =>
        value match {
          case Some(s) => myClass = s
          case None => null
        }
      case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
        null
    }, Duration.Inf)
    myClass
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all, you will just get `null` as your result.

Comment: @puhlen yes, but I can parse a null. I know that if it's null, the value doesn't exist in the db.

Comment: no, this will return null even if the value exists in the database.  If you want to block and extract the value you can use `Await.result` but it's better to do it asynchronously and stay in the future.

Comment: @puhlen I fixed and tested. You were right. I edited my answer.