# How to pass a Future data to the view?

Tags: scala, playframework

Iam trying to get data from a web weather API, I'am getting the data by using WSClient.

Actually, I can println and visualize the data like this :

```
val futureResponse: Future[WSResponse] = complexRequest.get()

def weather = Action {
   futureResponse.map {
     response =>
       println(response.json)
   }
   println(futureResponse)

   Ok(views.html.weather("data"))
}
```

but I have trouble passing it to the view layer using `Ok(views.html.weather("data"))` cause when i `println(futureResponse)` its not json data it shows : 
`Future(Success(AhcWSResponse(StandaloneAhcWSResponse(200, OK))))`

only `println(response.json)` shows the valid data i want to send but its unreachable outside.

Comment: You should rather use `Action.async` and apply the view within `Future.map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something on the lines of

```
def weather = Action.async {
   complexRequest.get().map(response => Ok(views.html.weather(response.json)))
}
```

So basically, the json is only available when the future is completed, so you can only pass it to the view inside the `map` function, also notice that I've used `Action.async` this creates an action that expects a `Future[WsResponse]` rather than just a `WsResponse`

Also bear in mind that the `Futures` are memoised, so if you store the reference to it in a `val` it will only execute once

EDIT: Fixed the future being stored in a `val` to avoid problems with the memoisation

Comment: What do you mean by `Future` being `memoised`? Although I understand what you want to say, its still very much misleading.

Comment: I mean that the `Future` will cache the result, so the call to the external service will happen only once. Memoization is the correct term for that, not sure why you find it misleading...

Comment: `Future` represents a `value` which may or may not have been computed yet. It has no "direct" relation to the computation itself (which is also reflected in the Future API, you will not see any way to interact with the computation itself). And hence, by definition - no memoization.

Comment: I'm not sure why you decided to declare your `futureResponse` as `val` in the first place. It is hard to come up with a real world scenario when this is what the developer wants.

Comment: I beg to differ, `Future` is directly linked to the computation, as is passed to it when you construct the future, and the computation it starts immediately and it will never be executed again unless you create a new one, which makes `Future` non referentially transparent, and that's why you have alternatives like scalaz Task...

Comment: I added async but it tells me that Symbole Action is deprecated !!! @Bruno

Comment: @SergGr I just used the code he provided to try to minimise the changes from the original example, I wouldn't do it myself otherwise

Comment: @S.Meziani haven't use Play in a while, but if that's deprecated you need to find what is the new way to create Asynchronouse actions, i.e. Actions where the value you return is a Future

Comment: @Bruno, my point is that I think when you warn that something might be bad, you should also provide a way to do it the right way.

Comment: @S.Meziani, could you update your question adding the new code and the exact warning text you see? Even in the [Play 2.7 docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/ScalaAsync) I can see examples that use `Action.async`

Comment: @SergGr good point, I've updated the code so we can forget about this matter that is not core to the question :)

Comment: @SergGr it was my code editor that was showing that warning but it worked well wen I compiled and executed, I guess I shoudn't take care about Intilij's warnings

Comment: @S.Meziani, unfortunately Scala is a complicated language not only for people but also for compilers and sometimes IntelliJ Idea shows wrong warnings. With some experience you'll learn to distinguish between real warnings and false positives by IDE.

Answer (score 0):

It's unreachable because you will have to use a callback method to access/pass the content inside Future. That's the reason `println(response.json)` inside `map` callback shows the data/content you are interested.

You may refer to [Accessing value returned by scala futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713642/accessing-value-returned-by-scala-futures)