# How to get Option[String] from Future[Option[String]]

Tags: scala, future

I am newbie to scala . I have a def which returns Future[Option[String]]. I have to return Option[String]] from that def. I cannot use Await.result. Any other alternatives

```
def processJson(key: String, value:String) : Future[Option[String]]{
}
```

I have gone through this link but could not figure.

http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-9-beginner-tutorial-using-scala-futures/#method-future-return-type

Any help please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing value returned by scala futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713642/accessing-value-returned-by-scala-futures)

Comment: Can you explain more of your problem? Why you have a **Future** at all? Why you need to just return a plain **Option**? Why you can not **Await**?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can either pass the Future without waiting for its completion (the calling method will deal with it) or you can call `Await.result` (but you said it isn't an option).

Anyway, I don't think you should return a Future if you don't want do deal with it, also just to process some JSON object (and not, for istance, to retrieve something from a remote server).

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

1. Await them ([see here for demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ajXkJ8HjTGSEShBXwtcPbQ)):

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def returnsAFuture: Future[Int] = Future {
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  10
}

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
println(Await.result(returnsAFuture, Duration.Inf))
```

2. Sleep the thread for a specific period of time ([see here for demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1Klt9R0yR1iPi0deKqP7sg) - based on the post you linked to):

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def returnsAFuture: Future[Int] = Future {
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  10
}

import scala.util.Success
returnsAFuture.onComplete {
  case Success(value) => println(value)
  case _ => println("No value found")
}

Thread.sleep(2000)
```

3. Leave the Future alone and deal with it later by mapping inside it ([see here for demo](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/HYNgU1NrSByV0JwkTpECTA)):

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def returnsAFuture: Future[Int] = Future {
  Thread.sleep(1000)
  10
}

val aNewFuture = returnsAFuture.map {_ * 2}

// do some other stuff

// access the result of the Future only when you absolutely have to

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
println(Await.result(aNewFuture, Duration.Inf))
```

The whole point of a Future is that you can deal with it under the assumption that it will resolve successfully by leaving it as a Future for as long as you can and dealing with any exceptions thrown at the last possible moment.

If you are using a framework like Play, you can just return a Future at the end and Play will resolve it for you. If not though, you will need to wait for the Future to finish at some point.

I would recommend doing option 3 though, so you can leave this until the last moment and not block your Thread unnecessarily early.

Comment: I cannot use await

Answer (score 0):

Probably when you are using futures, you shall await but there are rare such cases like that, because usually when you use futures you have a continuous running application so you would simply choose to use transformers (map, flatmap, for expressions) or consumers (foreach, onComplete) etc