# Get Future value from Scala MongoDB result

Tags: mongodb, scala

Using below code I'm attempting to select from MongoDB

```
val s : SingleObservable[Document]  = db.getCollection("Collection").find()
val f : Future[Document] = s.toFuture()
f.result(10 seconds)
```

but causes compiler error on line `f.result(10 seconds)`

```
No implicits found for parameter permit: CanAwait
```

[image]

How to access the Future value that contains the MongoDB document? Is there an implicit required?

Searching related questions such as [Accessing value returned by scala futures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17713642/accessing-value-returned-by-scala-futures) there is no requirement for an implicit parameter when accessing a value from `Future`. Why is the implicit required here?

Comment: The question you linked was asked 8 years ago (presumably with people using scala ~2.9?). I believe `Await.result(f, 10 seconds)` should do what you want in more modern versions.

Comment: You are missing the `import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` to execute computations in a new thread